# Why can't MediaItem be cast to SecureMediaItem?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the classes:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MediaItem : Video
    {
        //used to protect calling api from the incorrectly named video
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SecureMediaItem : MediaItem
    {
        [DataMember]
        public PlayerEmbedToken Token;
    }
```

Then I have the following code:

```
List<MediaItem> dummyItems = new List<MediaItem>();

 //cast the media item into a secure media item
SecureMediaItem retItem = (SecureMediaItem)dummyItems[mediaId];

//TODO: put in the Admin ID
retItem.Token.UserId = 1;
retItem.Token.IpAddress = VLSCore2.VlsSecurity.ParseIpFromString(ipAddress);
retItem.Token.UniquePlayerRef = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


return retItem;
```

However Im getting an error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'VLSCore2.Entities.Security.Api.MediaItem' to type
>   'VLSCore2.Entities.Security.Api.SecureMediaItem'.

This is just simply a widending cast is it not? Something stopping it like the DataContract attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It's the opposite of a widening cast. `SecureMediaItem` is more specific than `MediaItem`. You could cast a `SecureMediaItem` to a `MediaItem`, because a `SecureMediaItem` is a `MediaItem`. The other way around isn't working, because a `MediaItem` isn't necessarily a `SecureMediaItem`.

Comment: right so If I have a collection of media items and I want to put it into a secure media item then how do I do it?

Comment: That's possible, because *that* would be a widening cast: `var dummyItems = new List<MediaItem>(); dummyItems.Add(new SecureMediaItem()); // <- perfectly valid`.

Comment: BTW: The error you are getting is a runtime error. Most likely, the item you are trying to cast simply is a `MediaItem` instead of a `SecureMediaItem`. The following code will lead to this error: `var dummyItems = new List<MediaItem>(); dummyItems.Add(new MediaItem()); var x = (SecureMediaItem)dummyItems[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Daniel words to, may be, more intuitive understanding of this, if you immagine `MediaItem` like a circle, extending it you got a bigger circle `SecureMediaItem` . Casting in this case is like slicing the circle you choose. You can not slice *smaller* circle to get *bigger* one.

That is...

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting makes sense: you have a list of parent items, but you're trying to perform a downward cast.  The standard sort of example is something like this:

```
public class Shape { ... }

public class Circle : Shape
{
   public void FillCircle();
}

public class Square : Shape
{
   public void FillSquare();
}

...

Shape s = new Circle();
s.FillCircle();  // won't compile
Circle c = (Circle) s;
c.FillCircle();  // dangerous, but works
Square sq = (Square) s;  // runtime error
```

The cast to a Circle works because the particular shape happens to be a Circle.  However, the cast to a Square fails because while a Square is a Shape, a Shape is not necessarily a Square and a Circle is definitely not a Square.

In your case, you're trying to treat a MediaItem like a SecureMediaItem.  This is akin to treating a Shape like a Square: it will work when the Shape is a Square, but not when it's a Circle.

There is a way around this: [define your own explicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx).  However, I wouldn't recommend it as it's playing fast and loose with your object hierarchy.